# ZEND 2. Union . Add Limit to UNION query

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an sql query like the one below and i would like to create this in Zend Framework 2.

> ( SELECT id AS id FROM exp_personal_data ORDER BY town  ) UNION ( SELECT id AS id FROM pd_unregister )

I would like to have union and add to this LIMIT, ORDER BY etc.

$this->_select->combine($selectPdContest, 'union all');

When i write the query like this.

> $this->_select->combine($selectPdContest, 'union all')->limit('10);

Query looks like this:

> > ( SELECT id AS id FROM exp_personal_data ORDER BY town LIMIT 10  ) UNION ( SELECT id AS id FROM pd_unregister )

The limit is added only to firs select. I want the limit will to be added like this.

> ( SELECT id AS id FROM exp_personal_data ORDER BY town  ) UNION ( SELECT id AS id FROM pd_unregister ) LIMIT 10

How make this in Zend framework 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines will work,

$select1 = new Select();
$select1->combine($selectPdContest, 'union all');

$select3 = new Select();
$oneTwo = $select3->from(['sub' => $select1])->limit(10);

Comment: this works but i figure this by myself :D thanks for good answers to all:)

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1 (simple):

```
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $resultSet = $adapter->query("(SELECT user_id AS id FROM user ORDER BY id)  UNION  (SELECT account_id AS id FROM account) LIMIT 10",$adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    print_r($resultSet->toArray());die;
```

Solution 2 (Complex):

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

//sql query first part
$adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();//the db connection adapter
$select = new Select('user');
$select->columns(array('id' => 'user_id'));
$select->order('id');
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$statement = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select);

//sql query second part         
$select2 = new Select('account');
$select2->columns(array('id' => 'account_id'));
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$statement2 = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select2);

//combine the two statements into one        
$unionQuery = sprintf('%s UNION %s','('.$statement = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select).')',
'('.$statement2 = $sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject($select2).') LIMIT 10'); 

//execute the union query 
$resultSet = $adapter->query( $unionQuery, $adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);

print_r($resultSet->toArray());die;
```

Comment: I need limit to be added dynimicli :) by method limit to this sql.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: I need limit to be added  :)like this .I build query and than on this i write ->limit(10) and zend must know that i wanna limit this all query same with order by ofsset. I need new Select(); and add to variables in class limit and order :) i need to work on select object :D i think i write enough :)

Comment: if you bother to look at the answer and think a bit i am sure you can add the offset

Comment: So i can't build query in select object and use his methods to add limits ?